# N number of prior business days to extract

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to get the nth previous business date

```
BEGIN
    SELECT holiday_ind
      INTO v_holiday_ind
      FROM holiday_calendar 
       AND bus_date = L_bus_dt;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
          V_holiday_ind=’N’
END;
```

Now the user will input one date and an integer say n

I have to subtract n business days from the input date and give the output

For example if the user inputs May 26 2015 and 2 , the output should be May 20 2015 because may 25 2015 is memorial day and may 23 2015 sat and may 24 2015 sun

I tried following

```
FOR i IN 1..n
LOOP
BEGIN
   SELECT holiday_ind
     INTO v_holiday_ind
     FROM holiday_calendar 
      AND bus_date = L_bus_dt;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          V_holiday_ind=’N’
    END;
    L_bus_date := L_bus_date - n;
END LOOP;
```

But not working

Please help

Comment: What is the contents of `holiday_calendar` table: is there a list of business dates or something else?

Comment: it would help if you post details of your table.sample data and expected results

Comment: Holiday table takes input parameter as date and outputs whether it is holiday or not

Comment: Example the user will input the current business day and one parameter say 2  then my output should give 2 business days less for example if the user inputs  select holiday_func(sysdate,2) from dual the holiday_func should output as  24-Nov-2015 when sysdate='27-nov-2015'.Here 26-nov-2015 is holiday. In another example the function should return '03-sep-2015' when sysdate='08-sep-2015'. Here 07-sep-2015' is holiday

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in your code snippet and I think usage of FOR LOOP might not be that appropriate.

Here I assume that holiday_calendar contain information for weekends also.
The code will be something like this

```
begin
    while n > 0
    loop
        if l_bus_dt is holiday / weekend then
            l_bus_dt = l_bus_dt - 1
        otherwise
            l_bus_dt = l_bus_dt - 1
            n = n - 1
        end if
    end loop
end
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I did solve it by using exists clause of Of Pl/sql tables. In this way I did escape the no data found error and was able to assign to the second table wit indexes on from 1 to n